# Is it a good practice to use your full data set for predictions?

Tags: machine-learning

I know you're supposed to separate your training data from your testing data, but when you make predictions with your model is it OK to use the entire data set?

I assume separating your training and testing data is valuable for assessing the accuracy and prediction strength of different models, but once you've chosen a model I can't think of any downsides to using the full data set for predictions.

Comment: Can you explain how you mean to use this data to make "predictions"?

Comment: Sure, for example:

Suppose your train a model with historical stock market data, and then want to use it to predict future stock prices. As you're choosing, developing, tweaking which specific model to use you should set aside some of your data for training and testing.

But then once you're ready to use your model to make predictions about future stock prices, can you use your entire data set or should you only use your training data set still?

Comment: The whole point of creating a model is that you no longer need the training or testing data.  You simply apply the model on new data and, if the model is good, it will give you good predictions.  You can then validate those predictions later when you have future data.

Comment: In short, yes - once you've selected the best model and parameters you then retrain the model one time using the whole dataset; that's what you'll use making predictions going forward.

Comment: This is off-topic, rather on-topic in stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

You can use full data for prediction but better retain indexes of train and test data. Here are pros and cons of it:

Pro:

1. If you retain index of rows belonging to train and test data then you just need to predict once (and so time saving) to get all results. You can calculate performance indicators (R2/MAE/AUC/F1/precision/recall etc.) for train and test data separately after subsetting actual and predicted value using train and test set indexes.

Cons:

1. If you calculate performance indicator for entire data set (not clearly differentiating train and test using indexes) then you will have `overly optimistic` estimates. This happens because (having trained on train data) model gives good results of train data. Which depending of % split of train and test, will gives illusionary good performance indicator values.
2. Processing large test data at once may create memory bulge which is can result in crash in all-objects-in-memory languages like R.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you're right - when you've finished selecting your model and tuning the parameters, you should use all of your data to actually build the model (exception below).

The reason for dividing data into train and test is that, without out-of-bag samples, high-variance algorithms will do better than low-variance ones, almost by definition. Consequently, it's necessary to split data into train and test parts for questions such as:

1. deciding whether kernel-SVR is better or worse than linear regression, for your data
2. tuning the parameters of kernel-SVR

However, once these questions are determined, then, in general, as long as your data is generated by the same process, the better predictions will be, and you should use all of it.

An exception is the case where the data is, say, non-stationary. Suppose you're training for the stock market, and you have data from 10 years ago. It is unclear that the process hasn't changed in the meantime. You might be harming your prediction, by including more data, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are techniques for doing this, e.g. [k-fold cross-validation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-validation_(statistics)):

> One of the main reasons for using cross-validation instead of using the conventional validation (e.g. partitioning the data set into two sets of 70% for training and 30% for test) is that there is not enough data available to partition it into separate training and test sets without losing significant modelling or testing capability. In these cases, a fair way to properly estimate model prediction performance is to use cross-validation as a powerful general technique.

That said, there may not be a *good* reason for doing so if you have plenty of data, because it means that the model you're using *hasn't actually been tested* on real data. You're inferring that it probably will perform well, since models trained using the same methods on less data also performed well. That's not always a safe assumption. Machine learning algorithms can be sensitive in ways you wouldn't expect a priori. Unless you're very starved for data, there's really no reason for it.